# How to pass a ObservableArray to MVC controller ? Without Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, excel, knockout.js

I am having an observable array with a list of view model data which i need to pass to Normal controller which is having a return type of ActionResult

```
      public ActionResult Index(list<qualities> data)
        {
          return excelCon.DownloadTMExcel(data); //here i get actionResult as ReturnType
        }
```

Java script code :

```
var URL = "/DownloadExcel/Index?data="+self.qualities(); //self.qualities holds my entire list which hits break point in controller but i get Zero list . 
        window.open(URL, "_blank");
```

Actually the excat scenario is when everything works fine i get excelsheet downloded with new window open .

I need advice in how to pass observableArray like the way i am dealing .

**I tired also something like :**

```
var URL = "/DownloadExcel/Index?data="+ko.toJson(self.qualities()); //this dont to controller itself
```

I tried using Ajax call still it works one way i.e i can pass ObservableArray but ActionResult return Type it can't handle . always it goes to error function of ajax call and i wont get my excel downloaded  .

**The only case worked for me :** There is other scenario i just need to pass parameters to controller then i am able to open a new window and download relevant excel .

```
  var URL = "/DownloadExcel/Index?typeId="+2; 
        window.open(URL, "_blank"); //on open of new window i get excel downloaded
```

In Additional :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(list<qualities> data) // i get count ZERO
        {
            return View();
        }
```

*Using string Parameter*

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(string data) //break point at controller not even hitting 
            {
                return View();
            }
```

Any help is dearly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the value:

```
var URL = "/DownloadExcel/Index?data=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(ko.toJson(self.qualities()));
```

If `qualities` contains too much data for the query string, you can use a post. For example:

```
<form method="post" action="/DownloadExcel/Index">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" data-bind="value: qualities" />
    <button>Download</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ok let me check . Are you sure i will get something at `list<qualities> data`  in controller ? just curious becoz previously i tried like `ko.toJson(self.qualities())` i got error saying query string limit exceeded rightly so. cheers

Comment: Than the problem is that there's too much data in qualities or you have circular references in the objects. If there's too much data, you should post the data. Also do know that sending JSON to your action like this, it won't get deserialized automatically. You'd have to deserialize the JSON data into an object yourself.

Comment: yes i have more data in `self.qualities` . tried your way but i am getting nothing in controller .updated my observations at the end please look into it

Comment: HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found

The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long. this error i am facing

Comment: Using `window.open` results in a GET request. You could post the data using a form; see my update.

Comment: got my problem solved . what i done looks near similar to the you code . let me post my code .

Answer (score 1):

GET requests have smaller limits than POST in the specs.

Originally GET was intended to be small and simple while POST was created with the vision that someday it could be used for file-uploads and the like. The limits you'll face with POST aren't from the spec but server configuration and technically it can be without limit.

On top of this restriction on GETs is browsers take great effort to cut down long URLs to avoid buffer-overflow exploits of the past where specially crafted URLs could execute arbitary code on the clients machine.

So your solution is more likely a POST request. One way of doing this aside from AJAX is saving the data into a hidden field:

`<input type="hidden" id="json_to_send" name="json_to_send" />`

`document.getElementById('json_to_send').value  = JSON.stringify(myobjectarray);`

Then in PHP on the server-side:

`$myobjectarray = json_decode(html_entity_decode($_POST['json_to_send']));`